# SQL server Jobstep output to run bat file

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have sql job which has many job steps and each jobstep produces sql output which i need to run on the target envrionment. 
To run the sql job step outputs on target environment, i have batch file which includes list of .sql files.

My problem is when job step output created, it would include job step information in the firstline and also [SQLSTATE 01000].

I need to strip off the first line and replace [SQLSTATE 01000] with empty strings for all the .sql files in the directory.

What would be the best way to achieve this.

I am using sql server 2008 r2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ECHO =========================Batch File====================
@ECHO This example will create a database in Sql Server. It will simply execute the sql script created in directory...
msg * hello
for %%G in (C:\B*.sql) do  sqlcmd -S INDIA55-PPC\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P pass -d  DatabaseName  -i "%%G"

pause